# Securely storing a password on a local machine

Tags: node.js, passwords

I'm building a node.js command line tool meant to be run on a desktop that needs to store a users password. Is there a 'standard' way of doing this? If not should I simply store it in an encrypted file somewhere? If so, what location?

The way I would like this to work is the first time a user runs my module it will prompt them to create a password. It will then store that password somehow. In later runs it will retrieve and use that password without the user having to re-enter it.

Note: I need to be able to retrieve the password as a string. In other words I can't store a hash of the password.

Comment: the quick and easy way people generally do this is to store the password in an [environment variable](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Environment_variables) on the host machine

Comment: If you encrypt the password you just move the problem to securing the encryption key.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't think of that. Then what is the approach to take here?

Comment: I wasn't planning on supporting multiple logins. As far as OS I would prefer something OS independent as it could be run on Ubuntu, Windows, Mac, etc...

Comment: Who are you protecting against, what is the attacker's skill level and what is the value in $ of a successful attack?

Comment: This is the master password to a login management tool. The managed logins don't have to be stored, only the master. So if an attacker where to gain access it could be bad (The user could be storing their bank account login). But these are (probably) just normal people on normal computers so the chance of an attack attempt is rather small.

Comment: Keep the password in RAM after login. But what happens when the user walks away to gt a soda and another person attacks the computer. Additionally it is not as easy a problem as it may seem.